# Переадресация поддомена на папку с сохранением адреса (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

Есть следующий способ переадресации:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.sub\.site\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ sub/$1 [L,QSA]
```

который перенаправляет поддомен вида sub1.sub.site.ru на папку sub/ в корне сайта. При открытии адреса sub1.sub.site.ru/img , страница открывается правильно, но адресная строка переписывается в следующий вид sub1.sub.site.ru/sub/img

Вопрос. Как сделать чтобы адресная строка сохранялась? sub1.sub.site.ru/img

img - может быть любой папкой внутри sub/

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете .htaccess для реврайтов, то у меня подозрение, что шаблон `^/(.*)$` действительно работает...
По документации/практике - это не должно работать из-за символа "/".

Что касается сохранения адресной строки, то попробуйте использовать такое правило:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Да, это видимо двойной слэш // получился, но он переваривается, исправил у себя. К сожателию RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [PT,L,QSA] не сработал, всё равно адрес /sub/img открывается.

Comment: @Сергей нет, это не двойной слэш. Это url, который будет подставлен в этот шаблон, не будет начинаться со слэша, следовательно на выходе будет false. Что касается этого правила, то у меня оно работает. У вас других правил, htaccess-ов, etc случаем нет?

Comment: понятно, спасибо. У меня только четыре строчки и это не работает:

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\..*\..*\..*$`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [PT,L,QSA]`

Comment: @Сергей ok. Тогда пока что еще один вопрос: вы до этого не тестировали в своем браузере это же правило, но например с флагом [R=301] ?

Comment: думаете, на кэш браузера? Я конечно тестировал много чего, пока более-менее ровно не заработало. Но я сейчас зашел с планшета, с "чистого" браузера, то же самое выдаёт. Может ли быть проблема самого хостинга?

Comment: Видимо не хостинг, так как на локалке тоже самое

Comment: @Сергей ну тут все что угодно может быть. В конфиге Апача ничего особенного нет для этого виртуалхоста?

Comment: Проблема решилась при добавлении слэша после $1 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1/ [PT]` Дело было именно в нём, если вводился адрес без закрывающего слэша sub1.sub.site.ru/img Хотя правильно ли это?

Comment: @Сергей я уверен, что всё объяснимо. Кстати, операционная система какая и версия Апача на всякий случай?

Comment: Локально Windows Apache-2.2, хостинг Linux Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)

Comment: @Сергей Ха! так у меня аналогичное поведение. Я тестировал url со слэшом на конце, поэтому все было красиво. Но без слэша также редиректит на /sub/img/. И это правильно, т.к. такое поведение заложено в mod_dir, когда прилетает url без слэша на конце, указывающий на директорию.